# include-what-you-use with non-default g++ version

Tags: c++, cmake, iwyu

I'm trying to get [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org) working with my codebase for the first time.

My CentOS6 system has its default of g++ 4.4.7 installed.  I use g++ 4.9.3 for my C++11 project.  Those four choices are inflexible.

I effectively build the cmake database for my project like this:

```
%> export CXX=/path/to/gcc-4.9.3/bin/g++
%> export CC=/path/to/gcc-4.9.3/bin/gcc
%> mkdir $HOME/dev/build
%> cd $HOME/dev/build
%> cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE=/path/to/iwyu-6/bin/include-what-you-use
```

When I compile my project, I get output like this:

```
...
Warning: include-what-you-use reported diagnostics:
In file included from ../dev/src/whatever/foo.cc:13:
In file included from ../dev/src/whatever/foo.h:17:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/string:42:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:61:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/cstddef:44:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include <stddef.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~

../dev/src/whatever/foo.h should add these lines:

../dev/src/whatever/foo.h should remove these lines:
- #include <deque>  // lines 18-18

The full include-list for ../dev/src/trekcc/pss_dsl/pssTypes.h:
#include <string>  // for string
...
```

Great!  I don't need `deque.h` in that file, so the tool is somewhat working!

The warnings are discouraging though... Of course `stddef.h` is found by my actual compilation because it is actually defined below gcc-4.9.3 at:

```
/path/to/gcc-4.9.3/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/stddef.h
```

Q: How can I change my `${CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE}` variable so that the tool looks below `gcc-4.9.3` instead of the *default* of `gcc-4.4.7`?

Note that if I ask `cmake` to export the JSON compile commands, this entry looks something like:

```
{
  "directory": "/home/me/dev/build",
  "command": "/tools/gnu/gcc-4.9.3/bin/g++ -I../dev/foo -I../dev/bar -I/path/to/boost_1_66_0/include -I/path/to/graphviz-2.38.0/include -I/path/to/graphviz-2.38.0/include/graphviz -I../include -Wall --std=c++11 -Wno-parentheses -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -g -o dev/whatever/foo.cc.o -c /home/me/dev/src/whatever/foo.cc",
  "file": "/home/me/dev/src/whatever/foo.cc"
}
```

Thanks!

---

edit:

Per @KamilCuk's suggestion below, adding a `sysroot` to the iwyu command seems to make the 4.4.7 warning go away.

```
%> cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE="/path/to/iwyu-6/bin/include-what-you-use;-Xiwyu;--mapping_file=../iwyu.imp;--sysroot;/path/to/gcc-4.9.3/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.3"
```

It cannot find basics like `<map>` or `<vector>` now, but the 4.4.7 warning has gone away, which tells me we're on the right track!

Using `--sysroot /path/to/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3` doesn't solve that problem.  I get many errors like this, for many common files:

```
Warning: include-what-you-use reported diagnostics:
../dev/whatever/foo.cc:12:10: fatal error: 'sstream' file not found
#include <sstream>
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `--sysroot /path/to/gcc-4.9.3/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.3/`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should just use a toolchain file. Often in my project (especially for cross-compiling), I will make a dedicated folder where I put all of my toolchains and other cmake commands.

```
my_proj
    cmake 
        other_gcc.cmake
    CMakeLists.txt
    ...
```

For example, here is one version of `other_gcc.cmake` I use for cross-compiling:

```
# Define our host system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

# Define the cross compiler locations
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

# Define the sysroot path for the RaspberryPi distribution in our tools folder
#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{AARCH64_LINUX_TOOLS_DIR}/aarch64-linux-gnu/sysroot)

# Use our definitions for compiler tools
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
```

This is relevant for you because you also need to change the compiler. Probably you can comment off those first 3 `CMAKE_SYSTEM_` commands for your use case.

Then during the configure step, you just tell Cmake that you want to use this toolchain file:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/other_gcc.cmake ..
```